# element.scrollIntoView for some reason doesnt works in element.addEventListener("input", ...)

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add scroll to the first found element to search on my page https://be1zebub.github.io/elite-emotes-collection/
for some reason it didnt works in `addEventListener("input", ...)`
but it works fine if im run same code in chrome-dev-tools console

my code:

```
function isInViewport(elem) {
    const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    const vw = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    const vh = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= vh &&
        rect.right <= vw
    );
}

document.getElementById("search_input").addEventListener("input", function() {
    let userinput = this.value;
    let has_visible_in_view = false;

    document.querySelectorAll(".emote").forEach(function(emote) {
        let is_visible = emote.getAttribute("data-bs-original-title").match(userinput);
        emote.style.opacity = is_visible ? 1 : 0.25;

        if (is_visible && has_visible_in_view == false) {
            if (isInViewport(emote)) {
                has_visible_in_view = true;
            } else {
                emote.scrollIntoView({block: "center"});
                has_visible_in_view = true;
            }
        }
    });
}, false);
```

the minimum code that works when im run in in chrome-dev-tools console:

```
function isInViewport(elem) {
    const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    const vw = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    const vh = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= vh &&
        rect.right <= vw
    );
}

let userinput = document.getElementById("search_input").value;
let has_visible_in_view = false;

document.querySelectorAll(".emote").forEach(function(emote) {
    let is_visible = emote.getAttribute("data-bs-original-title").match(userinput)
    emote.style.opacity = is_visible ? 1 : 0.25;

    if (is_visible && has_visible_in_view == false) {
        if (isInViewport(emote)) {
            has_visible_in_view = true;
        } else {
            emote.scrollIntoView({block: "center"});
            has_visible_in_view = true;
        }
    }
});
```

*you can test it on https://be1zebub.github.io/elite-emotes-collection/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'input' event not exist you can use keyup event

in below sample try write `win` in input to make it run

```js
    function isInViewport(elem) {
        const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        const vw = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
        const vh = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= vh &&
            rect.right <= vw
        );
    }

    document.getElementById("search_input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        let userinput = this.value;
        let has_visible_in_view = false;

        document.querySelectorAll(".emote").forEach(function(emote) {
            let is_visible = emote.getAttribute("data-bs-original-title").match(userinput);
            emote.style.opacity = is_visible ? 1 : 0.25;
            if (is_visible && has_visible_in_view == false) {
                if (isInViewport(emote)) {
                    has_visible_in_view = true;
                } else {
                    emote.scrollIntoView({block: "center"});
                    has_visible_in_view = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }, false);
```

```html
<input id="search_input"/>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>

<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="wrong">wrong</div>
<div class="emote" data-bs-original-title="win">win</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - it worked <3
In fact, idk where "input" came from - yesterday I used "keyup" :D.
It is also weird, the part of my code related to the opacity change works, but there is scrolling not works.